# How to set Image size and positon dynamically

Tags: java, android

I want to initiate margin and size of image .i have code in xml and i would like to write it dynamically.I have read all the answers given in Stackoverlow But i could n't understand it.Kindly help me out.I am attaching the xml code below

```
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coin1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/coin2"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ten_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            />
```

For this Xml I would like to write it in java code.

Comment: *But i could n't understand it* then why you think that you be able to understand yet another answer?

Comment: I dono how to write the code dynamically and  i like to learn.Is it wrong to learn new things.

Comment: @Selvin, you should already know, *I could 'nt understand it* == please provide code I can copy paste, I have no idea what I'm doing...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 ll_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_layout);//parent layout of imageView 
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);//initialize imageview
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(100, 100));//set hight and width
            //or
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.iv_width), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.iv_height)));
            //or
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            ll_layout.addView(imageView);//add image in parent layout
```

Comment: he has *`layout_toRightOf`* so obviously he is not using `LinearLayout` as parent layout

Answer (score 0):

```
 RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_id);
 ImageView iv = new ImageView(YourActivity.this);
 iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frnd_inactive));
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20,20);
 layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.ten_btn);
 layoutParams.setMargins(35, 25, 0, 0);
 iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
 root.addView(iv);
```

Note these all values will be in pixel. To convert your dp measurement to pixel try this

```
 Resources r = mContext.getResources();
 int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    yourdpmeasure, 
    r.getDisplayMetrics()
 );
```